# [GWT][Java] Scientific notation auto rounded?

Tags: java, gwt, number-formatting

I need to use Scientific notation to represent a value.
I use this code but the value is rounded and I don't want that...

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat;
...
Double value = Double.parseDouble("0.00000012");
String formatted = NumberFormat.getScientificFormat().format(value);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

The result is:

```
1E-7
```

and not

```
1.2E-7
```

Could you help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: Double sometimes loses precision and stuff, if you need be really accurate (science, money) you should use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same format pattern used in funkyjelly's answer should work with GWT's `NumberFormat` type:

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat;
...
Double value = Double.parseDouble("0.00000012");
String formatted = NumberFormat.getFormat("0.#####E0").format(value);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: This is the proper way! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with the standard `java.text.DecimalFormat`

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
...

Double value = Double.parseDouble("0.00000012");
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.#####E0");
String formatted = formatter.format(value);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

This prints out : 1.2E-7

Comment: Usign java.text.* I get an error...  I think that java.text.* is not supported in GWT :(

Answer (score 0):

With your GWT NumberFormat, can you try the below and see if it works ? (eg using BigDecimal instead of Double)

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getScientificFormat().format(new BigDecimal("0.00000012")));
```

Comment: Same output :( 1E-7